# Mandrill API sending scheduled emails with send_at

Tags: ruby, email, mandrill

The documentation isn't very clear how to use the send_at parameter. I am sending a scheduled email using the function below. I have tried different versions of the datetime required by the API documentation.

All my emails are being send right away and not scheduled.

```
  def send_member_email_batch(current_user, recipient_emails, recipient_names, subject, body, scheduled)
    m = Mandrill::API.new ENV["MANDRILL_APIKEY"]

    recipient_emails.each_with_index do |recipient, index|
      to_address = (recipient_emails.length > 1) ? [{"email"=>recipient,"name"=>recipient_names[index], "type"=>"to"}] :
            [{"email"=>recipient,
              "name"=>recipient_names[index],
              "type"=>"to"}, 
            {"email"=>current_user.email,
              "name"=>current_user.name,
              "type"=>"cc"}]

      message = { 
        :from_name=> current_user.name,
        :from_email=> current_user.email,
        :to=> to_address,
        :subject=> temp_subject, 
        :html=> temp_body,
        :auto_text=>true,
        :tags=> ["members"],    
        :track_opens=>true,
        :track_clicks=>true,        
        :preserve_recipients => false
      } 
        time_now = DateTime.now.utc
        time_now += (1 + ((5-time_now.wday) % 7))
        time_now = time_now.change({hour: 12, min: 3, sec: 0 }).strftime('%F %T')
        puts time_now #2015-10-10 12:03:00

        send_at = time_now

      #puts "to: #{recipient}, subject = #{temp_subject}, message = #{temp_body}"
      begin
        result = m.messages.send message, send_at
        puts result #email is not scheduled
      rescue Mandrill::Error => e
        puts "A mandrill error occurred: #{e.class} - #{e.message}" 
        next
      end
    end
  end
```

https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.ruby.html#method=send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, you have to include async and ip_pool if you want to use scheduled emails..

```
async = false
ip_pool = "Main Pool"
send_at = "example send_at"
result = mandrill.messages.send message, async, ip_pool, send_at
```

Comment: Those parameters aren't required to use send_at. It's likely that you're seeing a 'queued' response, though, since you're not sending it async instead.

Comment: @Kaitlin-Mandrill Interesting that you work at mandrill and telling me otherwise. It is required to get the API to work. I actually banged my head on this for hours until I figured it out.

Comment: @Kaitlin-Mandrill Hi Kaitlin, could you help to have a look at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33730115/mandrill-embed-image-cannot-get-interpreted-properly Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

from the mandrill api doc:

when this message should be sent as a UTC timestamp in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. If you specify a time in the past, the message will be sent immediately. An additional fee applies for scheduled email, and this feature is only available to accounts with a positive balance.

If I would have to guess I would guess that `send_at = time_now` needs to become `send_at = time_now.to_s` to make send_at respect the format needed.

Comment: Would you happen to know how far in advance you can schedule with Mandrill? [SparkPost and Sendgrid only allow scheduling 3 days in advance](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128911/how-can-i-schedule-emails-to-be-sent-more-than-3-days-in-advance).